# What is the relation between effective mass and majority charge carrier

Tags: mass, charge, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I am studying a semiconductor. My System has n-type dominating  character.
I am getting effective mass for top of the valence band (VBM) as 5.04 while for bottom of conduction (CBM) band it is 0.20.

My question is:

Is it okay to have higher effective mass for the VBM where my system is showing n-type character?

Comment: The effective mass is directly related to the curvature of the bands. Why would the valance band effective mass have anything to do with the material being n-type?

Comment: My main goal is to study thermoelectric properties of the material. There may be any relation between type dominating charge carriers and effective mass. So I am looking a direct relation of effective mass with the majority  charge carriers. Thank you.